# Comparing two postgres dump files

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

How to compare postgres dump files?
I have two dump files, dump1 and dump2 . And I want to compare these two dump files.

Any help will be appreciated..

Thank you

Comment: Depends on what you would actually want to see as a result. If both are made with the same version and settings diff or a similar text comparison program might get you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use beyond compare if windows is been used and use kompare if linux(fedora) is been used also if linux is used than you can use different command like `sdiff` example is provided in [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-compare-two-files-under-linux-or-unix/), other commands are `diff`,`comm -23 filedump1 fuledump2`,`sort filedump1 > filedump1.sorted
sort fuledump2 > fuledump2.sorted
diff filedump1.sorted fuledump2.sorted` etc are utilities to compare text in files

Comment: @giorgiomugnaini yes definitely :)

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSql's dump files are like normal data files..
you can use any utility/tool to see the difference between them.. Most of the OS has build in utilities for this

For example:

- linux:

vimdiff dump1 dump2
 (http://alvinalexander.com/linux-unix/vimdiff-see-multiple-file-differences-visually)

- On Windows:

fc dump1 dump2
 (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fc.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :) The provided commands does the work. links are just for extra read

Answer (score 0):

I would use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare the schema dumps. Data dumps will not be sorted (I just opened [a bug report about this](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2011-04/msg00132.php)), but there are better tools to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a simple textual comparison, to start with (`diff` command or similar tools).

If you need more than that, there are tools that make database comparisons. For example:

- [apgdiff](https://github.com/fordfrog/apgdiff) compares dumps - but only the schema (not the data). Written in Java.
- [pg_comparator](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/projects/pgFoundry/pg-comparator/pg_comparator/) compares data in 2 tables (not from dumps, but from 1 or 2 live databases). It is written in Perl.

Disclaimer: I have not tried them.

Comment: First link leads to an "it works" page. :Not sure if: some kind of click bait or broken link

Comment: Second link leads to bodybuilding page.

Comment: I have updated the links. Now they should work fine.